# TListBox custom style not show in Android App

Tags: android, listbox

I have an TListBox with some items. Each item has their own style (basically two little rectangle colors and one text).

When I compile App for Windows it looks great, but when I compile for Android it only look with one rectangle color (gray) and text.

ListBox.DefaultItemStyles.Itemstyle is set to: colorlistboxitemstyle

Each ListBoxItemX.StyleLookUp is set to: ListBoxItemXStyleX.

Please, why in Windows looks great and in Android looks bad?.

Thanks!.

Comment: What do you mean by windows, are you running app in emulator?

Comment: Could you provide screenshots? What versions are you running in the emulator and on your phone?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your reply.

Sorry for my english, I have not explained well...

I want to list some items with an ListView in Firemonkey (Delphi), and I need that items show two color squares and an text field. For it, I have done this configurations:

(Pick in each link to see the image attached)

[I set itemstyle to colorlistboxitemstyle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e3kn.png)

[By each item, I have done an custom item style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CKnt.png)

[Here you can view the custom style for that item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS8pI.png)

[And I can look the style working correctly in design time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKZ7H.jpg)

If I compile the application for Win32 platform (for Windows), I can see my app running with ListBox styles as I can see in design time... working very good.

[But if I compile for Android (executing directly in Android phone (no emulators), I only see one square gray and text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W8wE.jpg)

I don't know why..., I'm searching for info but I can't find an explanation.

Thanks for all!!